# Hover color on Kendo UI Bar Chart bars

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to find a way to completely change the color of a Kendo UI Bar Chart bar when it is hovered over. I do know that there is the series.highlight.color config option, but this seems to add only a tint in that color. I am wanting to completely replace the normal bar color with a different hover color. I have been pouring through the docs but can't seem to find a configuration option to do this even though it seems like there has to be a way to do this through Kendo config options without having to resort to hacking it.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you can post some code (preferably an example of what you have so far) it would massively increase your chances of a decent answer.

Comment: In Kendo UI, pretty much everything is just configuration options in JSON. So there really is no applicable code to offer. Like I mentioned above, I tried setting series.highlight.color, but that wasn't it, I believe due to an opacity set in Kendo's built-in SVG code.

Comment: I have decided to try to directly target the generated SVG to change it, which does require code but it really isn't applicable to this question. However I would still be very interested whether or not there is a Kendo configuration switch in the API to do this. But curiously it seems that there is not unless there is something I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[series.highlight.visual](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.highlight.visual)** property to draw the bar with a solid color:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [{
      type: "bar",
      data: [1, 2],
      highlight: {
        visual: function(e) {          
          var origin = e.rect.origin;
          var bottomRight = e.rect.bottomRight();
          var topRight = e.rect.topRight();
          var topLeft = e.rect.topLeft();

          var c = "green";
          var bc = "#555";

          var path = new kendo.drawing.Path({
            fill: {color:  c,opacity: 1,},
            stroke: {color: bc,opacity:  0.7,width: 2,}
          })
          .moveTo(origin.x, bottomRight.y)
          .lineTo(bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y)
          .lineTo(topRight.x, topRight.y)
          .lineTo(topLeft.x, topLeft.y)
          .close();

          return path;    
        }
      }
  }]
});
```

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/OSEZO)**

Within the visual function you can get at the item and base the color on value or another field, etc.

Comment: Very interesting solution! I will try this out. Thank you!